# Bluetooth Mouse workd just for a while

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth

I have a A4teack bluetooth mouse (BT-630).
When I add it  via "Add a device" window, It works just for a while (~10min).
If I remove it using `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers` and add it again it will work again for a while an became inactive again.

How can I solve the problem?
Is it specific to this model or other blue-tooth mouthes have this issue too?

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Sony provided diver of blue-tooth adapter. Installing broadcom  driver solved the issue.